# Chnage color bar with contains

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

How to change bar color by using contains funstion "%accepted". Accepted with XX, Accepted without XX bars available so need to make both similar color.
In Source code not working

{"%accepted":#008005}
{"%accepted":#008005}

Comment: What have you tried already?